Carleson's Theorem on infinite dimensions
Carleson's Theorem says that any Fourier series of an $L^2$ function on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$ has pointwise convergence almost everywhere on $\mathbb{T}$.
If I have $L^2(\mathbb{T}) \otimes W$ with $W$ being a finite Hilbert space ($\simeq$ the space of $|W|$-dimensional vectors of $L^2$-functions), it is straightforward to extend the theorem (we just apply the theorem component-wise, considering an orthonormal basis for $W$).
Is the theorem true also for an infinite-dimensional $W$?

The finite-dimensional version works because the finite union of the measure-zero sets where each coordinate function does not converge is also measure zero. For countably infinite measure-zero sets, this is still true. But it is obviously not true in general for a collection of measure-zero sets with the power of the continuum.

@PaulSinclair it makes sense, but this means that the result should hold if W is separable, right? But I can't think of a formal argument involving the definition of limit.

If $f \in L^2 \otimes W$, and we choose a basis ${w_n}$ for $w$, then we can express $f = \sum_n f_nw_n$ for $L^2$ functions $f_n$. Each of these is limit of a sequence $F_{n,i}$ of Taylor polynomials in $e^{i\theta}$ except on a set of measure zero, which we can consider common to all $n$ for the separable case. Now we want to form $F_i = \sum_n F_{n,i}w_n$ as the Taylor polymomials for $f$. But herein lies the problem. Just because $\sum_n f_nw_n$ converges does not mean $ \sum_n F_{n,i}w_n$ sums also converge for each $i$. This is unrelated to the pointwise failures of the $f_n$.
